# Creating Production -> staging flow, how to skip email addresses when doing mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, php

I want to run mysqldump or basically, anything that lets me easily export / import mysql db from one server into another.

Thing is: I want to export production data as staging / integration / demo data. That means, prior to importing the data, *all* user data must be gone. We had it one time, that the users got imported, and because the system ran a cron job, the server started sending out 200'000 emails. Can you imagine? yes yes, just disable the cronjob prior to import, but accidents happen. So importing user data *and then* deleting them is not an option.

Optimally I want to just ignore certain columns where there is an email, or replace that email with a test email string.

Is there something that helps me with that?

php is what we use for the application, so any php import export tool is a possibility as well.

Comment: Did you thought about creating a view on top of your data but just changing the emails you need to change, and then dump this view content to import somewhere else instead of dumping the underlying tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Dump the database
2. Pump it in the temporary database
3. Empty columns you do not want to transfer
4. Dump the temporary database
5. Transfer it

Answer (score 1):

Native `mysqldump` doesn't have a feature to ignore columns. But you can do this by exporting that specific tables as CSV then import it to your staging.

## Example

- DB: bhuvi
- Total tables: 3
- No. of tables I need to ignore some columns: 1

[image]

**testtable** has some secret data.

```
select * from testtable;
+------+----------+-----------------+
| id   | name     | email           |
+------+----------+-----------------+
|    1 | sqladmin | sql@admin.com   |
|    2 | bhuvi    | bhuvi@gmail.com |
|    3 | dba      | dba@xyz.com     |
|    4 | stack    | ex@stack.com    |
|    5 | user     | user@test.com   |
+------+----------+-----------------+
```

### View for showing dummy emails

```
create view secret as ( select id, name , 'test@test.com' as email from testtable);
select * from secret;
+------+----------+---------------+
| id   | name     | email         |
+------+----------+---------------+
|    1 | sqladmin | test@test.com |
|    2 | bhuvi    | test@test.com |
|    3 | dba      | test@test.com |
|    4 | stack    | test@test.com |
|    5 | user     | test@test.com |
+------+----------+---------------+
```

### Export the data as CSV from shell

```
mysql -u root -p bhuvi -e "select * from secret" | sed 's/\t/"|"/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > testtable.csv
```

### Dump all the tables with schema only

```
 mysqldump --no-data -u root -p bhuvi > bhuvi.sql
```

### Dump the table which are import as it is

```
DBTODUMP=bhuvi
SQL="SET group_concat_max_len = 10240;"
SQL="${SQL} SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_name separator ' ')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='${DBTODUMP}'"
SQL="${SQL} AND table_name NOT IN ('testtable')"
TBLIST=`mysql -uroot -ppass -AN -e"${SQL}"`
mysqldump -uroot -ppass ${DBTODUMP} ${TBLIST} > bhuvi_tables.sql
```

### Restore the DB:

#### Restore schema:

```
mysql -u root -p stage < bhuvi.sql
```

#### Restore full tables:

```
mysql -u root -p stage < bhuvi_tables.sql
```

#### Restore CSV file:

```
 mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by="|"  --fields-enclosed-by='"'  --verbose --local -u root -p stage testtable.csv
```

### Check the data:

```
mysql> select * from testtable;
+------+----------+---------------+
| id   | name     | email         |
+------+----------+---------------+
|    1 | sqladmin | test@test.com |
|    2 | bhuvi    | test@test.com |
|    3 | dba      | test@test.com |
|    4 | stack    | test@test.com |
|    5 | user     | test@test.com |
+------+----------+---------------+
```

## Or simple method: Purge the email column after restore

```
udpate testtable set email='test@test.com'
```

Comment: is there a trick to have the update basically run in one transaction? I am not an sql expert, but if I run the update in the same commit as the inserts, it might just work good enough, right? then again, if I have too many inserts, a huuuuge commit will probably break the server / run out of memory.

Comment: Try to update in chunks. like update 1000 rows -> commit then update next 1000 rows -> commit. Else try the steps which I answered. Dump all tables along with your email column table, Expert specific tables as CSV using views or use this `mysql -u root -p dbname -e "select id, name , 'test@test.com' as email from testtable" > | sed 's/\t/"|"/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > testtable.csv`